# How to deploy my PHP website?

Tags: php, deployment

This is a very NOOb questions, I know, but this is my first website that I made, and I have no idea how to deploy it. I made it using PHP, and my file structure is as follows:

```
Includes 
Public
  ->images
  ->...
  ->...
  ->userview
```

All my files that will be accessed by the users are in the userview document, and my entry page which is login.php, is also there. How should I deploy it?

I tried just copying the files over to my hoast using filezilla, but it gives a glorious 404 and 403 error depending what i am trying to access.

The output for `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`  is /var/chroot/home/content/40/7141640/html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying is right, but you should create a file called index.php (within root folder of your webhosting folder) which is mostly called first. But calling login.php directly should work either.

Wrong path: try sth. like this as path:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/public/userview/menulogged.php"
```

Every webhoster is different, so it´s difficult to find the correct path for me, just ask your webhoster if this doesn´t work or try another directory.

Comment: I made a index.php that calls the file inside, but it doesn't work. require_once("public/userview/menulogged.php"); It says that the file doesn't exist. Am I writing it wrong the path to it?

Comment: @Pillblast, don't forget that if you are developing on a Windows box and hosting on a *nix box that your filename is now case-sensitive.

Comment: It's not working like that either. Is it ok to move my files in the root folder? Is it a good practice? @Brad, I know, I made all my files lowercase to start with

Comment: Show us the output of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: /var/chroot/home/content/40/7141640/html this is the output

Comment: okay, assuming you have uploaded all files and dirs into this folder (html) this should work: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/public/userview/menulogged.php"      --   if not, post all folders you can see if you logged in via FTP

Comment: thank you a lot. it worked thanks to the /. now i just have to modify some other parths, but I know how. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: actually i realized that i declared all my paths relative to this:  define('SITE_ROOT', 'C:'.DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'ArmyCreator'); how can i change it to use the path from the hosting website?